# "presented in the piece"

Tags: meaning-in-context

At work I've got to interpret the following clause:

> Liquid crystal devices consisting of a liquid crystal layer sandwiched between two sheets or plates of glass or plastics, whether or not fitted with electrical connections, **presented in the piece** or cut to special shapes and not constituting articles described more specifically in other headings of the Nomenclature.

What I don't understand is the bold part and was wondering if you could help. What is being presented? What does 'the piece' refer to? Or maybe 'presented in the piece' is idiomatic for something?

Comment: This sounds odd if not incorrect. Can yu provide the source or additional context, please?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Sure. I can't find its actual source on the internet, but it's been cited at quite a few places. The original source is the so-called Explanatory Notes of the Harmonized System (2007 edition), published by the World Customs Organization.

Comment: By searching for the phrase "in the piece", I've found a lot of references in customs documents, especially about textiles, but I haven't found a glossary that explains its meaning.

Comment: What would be an educated guess of its meaning?

Comment: @Taiki It seems to be jargon of import law. Maybe someone who knows for sure will reply.

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs. I’ll find a lawyer to talk to.